# installing geopandas with conda, can't find dependencies libgcc-ng

Tags: python, conda, geopandas

I am trying to install geopandas with conda.

I have created a fresh environment

```
conda create --name gp python=2
```

Then tried to install geopandas

```
conda install geopandas
```

Which returns

> Error: Could not find some dependencies for geopandas: rtree,
>   libspatialindex >=1.9.0,<1.10.0a0, libgcc-ng >=7.3.0, matplotlib-base
>
> Did you mean one of these?
>
> ```
> geopandas, pandas, biopandas
> ```
>
> Did you mean one of these?
>
> ```
> rtree, r-tree, r-htree
> ```
>
> Did you mean one of these?
>
> ```
> matplotlib-base, matplotlib-venn, matplotlib
> ```

So I have installed `libgcc-ng`:

```
conda install -c anaconda libgcc-ng
```

Then tried to install `libspatialindex`:

```
conda install -c conda-forge libspatialindex
```

But this returns:

> Error: Could not find some dependencies for libspatialindex: libgcc-ng
>   >=7.3.0

Comment: Are you installing Geopandas from conda-forge? It often causes dependency issues , when installing from defaults. Try `conda config --env --add channels conda-forge` and then `conda config --env --set channel_priority strict` before installing geopands into new env.

Comment: off topic how do you find geopandas so far?

Answer (score 1):

If the point of the new env is to have `geopandas` in it, then let Conda know that right from the start and it can solve the dependencies upfront:

```
conda create -n gp python=2 geopandas
```

However, as @martinfleis points out, you may still have channel priority issues. Testing on a `linux-64` platform, I was able to install `geopandas=0.4.0` from `anaconda` channel alone, but to install `geopandas=0.5.0` required both `anaconda` and `conda-forge`, and could be provided in either priority. In @martinfleis's testing, only giving `conda-forge` priority worked. Hence,

```
conda create -n gp -c conda-forge -c defaults --override-channels python=2 geopandas
```

would be the consensus command.

---

#### Note on Channel Priorities

It is possible to change channel priorities at the configuration level, as in @martinfleis's comment to OP, and in this case would make it so that the first command above works exactly like the second. However, one should only make such a change of it really coincides with your channel preferences - not to achieve a particular installation.

The alternative, as demonstrated in the second command above, is to temporarily specify channel priorities in a `create` or `install` command.  In that command, `-c conda-forge` coming first gives it priority over `-c defaults`.  The `--override-channels` flag disables whatever other channels you might have in permanent configuration settings.

Additionally, one can still specify individual packages to come from a particular channel by prefixing `<channel>::` to the package name. For example, if in the second command, I still wanted to source Python from `defaults`, it would be `defaults::python=2`.

If you have more than a couple of exceptions that you want to specify, then it's probably time to consider installing from a YAML.

Comment: The issue with Geopandas is that it requires geospatial dependencies which quite often cause compatibility issues. That's why you want to install not just Geopandas, but ideally all its dependencies from `conda-forge`. I tried your method but got only UnsatisfiableError.

Comment: @martinfleis did you try the equivalent of your suggestion? I.e., `conda create -n gp -c conda-forge -c defaults --override-channels python=2 geopandas`

Comment: that works. I would suggest editing the answer not to produce an error. Anyway, I agree with your point on channel priorities. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @martinfleis great, and thanks for the feedback! I've updated it to reflect that.